# Superclass resets already active objects

Tags: java

It's a little bit difficult but i'll try to explain my problem. I've created a program with a superclass (`RichIndustrialist`) two subclasses (`PredecessorRichIndustrialist` and another one I didn't add) and 4 subclasses to these subclasses (`CrazyRichIndustrialist` and another 3). Now, the program is too difficult to explain but the problem is actually simple. My constructor is in the superclass and every subclass use it to initilize. Every time I create a new subclass object like `CrazyRichIndustrialist`, it resets all the already existed subclasses (from any subclass) to the value of the new object. I don't know how to fix this. Thank you in advance...

`RichIndustrialist`:

```
package Mortal;

import java.util.Random;

public class RichIndustrialist implements Mortal {

    private static String Name;
    private static double holdings;
    private static int Alive;

    public RichIndustrialist(String Rich_Name, double Rich_holdings) {
        this.Name = Rich_Name;
        this.holdings = Rich_holdings;
        this.Alive = 1;
    }

    public int isAlive() {
        return (this.Alive);
    }

    public void setHoldings(double new_holdings) {
        this.holdings = new_holdings;
    }

    public double getHoldings() {
        return (this.holdings);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (this.Name);
    }

    public void die() {
        this.Alive = 0;
    }

    public void getHeritage(double heritage) {
        this.holdings = this.holdings + heritage;
    }
}
```

`PredecessorRichIndustrialist`:

```
package Mortal;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class PredecessorRichIndustrialist extends RichIndustrialist {

    private static String Name;
    private static double holdings;
    private RichIndustrialist[] successors = {};
    private static int Alive;

    public PredecessorRichIndustrialist(String Rich_Name, double Rich_holdings) {
        super(Rich_Name,Rich_holdings);
    }

    public void die() {
        super.die();
    }

    public void Inheritance(double holdings, RichIndustrialist[] successors) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < successors.length) {
            int Alive = successors[i].isAlive();
            System.out.println(Alive);
            if (Alive == 0) {
                removeSuccessor(successors[i]);
                i++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addSuccessor(RichIndustrialist new_successor) {
        RichIndustrialist[] new_successors = new RichIndustrialist[successors.length + 1];
        if (successors.length == 0) {
            new_successors[0] = new_successor;
            successors = new_successors;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < successors.length; i++) {
                new_successors[i] = successors[i];
            }
            new_successors[new_successors.length - 1] = new_successor;
        }
        this.successors = new_successors;
    }

    public void removeSuccessor(RichIndustrialist removed_successor) {
        RichIndustrialist[] new_successors = new RichIndustrialist[this.successors.length - 1];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.successors.length; i++) {
            if (!this.successors[i].equals(removed_successor)) {
                new_successors[j] = this.successors[i];
            } else {
                j--;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    public RichIndustrialist[] getSuccessors() {
        return successors;
    }
}
```

`CrazyRichIndustrialist`:

```
package Mortal;

import java.util.Random;

public class CrazyRichIndustrialist extends PredecessorRichIndustrialist {

    private RichIndustrialist[] successors = {};
    private static String Name;
    private static double holdings;
    private static int Alive;

    public CrazyRichIndustrialist(String Rich_Name, double Rich_holdings) {
        super(Rich_Name,Rich_holdings);
    }
    public void die() {
        super.die();
        Inheritance(getHoldings(),getSuccessors());
    }   

    public void addSuccessor(RichIndustrialist new_successor) {
        super.addSuccessor(new_successor);
    }

    public void removeSuccessor(RichIndustrialist removed_successor) {
        super.removeSuccessor(removed_successor);
    }

    public void Inheritance (double holdings , RichIndustrialist[] successors) {
        super.Inheritance(holdings, successors);
        for (int i=0; i<successors.length-1; i++)
        {
            double random = new Random().nextDouble();
            double amount = this.holdings * random;
            successors[i].getHeritage(amount);
            holdings = this.holdings - amount;
        }
        successors[successors.length-1].getHeritage(this.holdings);
        this.holdings = 0;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return super.getName();
    }
    public double getHoldings(){
        return super.getHoldings();
    }
    public RichIndustrialist[] getSuccessors(){
        return super.getSuccessors();
    }
    public void setHoldings(double new_holdings){
        super.setHoldings(new_holdings);
    }
    public int isAlive() {
        return super.isAlive();
    }
    public void getHeritage(double heritage) {
        super.getHeritage(heritage);
    }

}
```

Comment: try to provide short code to try and help quickly

Answer (score 7):

Most of your fields are `static`. What that means is that all the instances of your classes share the same value. When you call the constructor, the static fields are modified, which affects all the existing instances.

For example:

```
this.Name = Rich_Name;
```

should actually have been written:

```
RichIndustrialist.Name = Rich_Name;
```

You can read about the difference between instance and class (or static) members in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: Thank you all... I checked to non static and it fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 6):

The following fields should be declared as non-static.  When these fields are declared as static each `RichIndustrialist` instance will share these fields and their assigned values.  Declaring them as non-static allows each `RichIndustrialist` instance to have its own copy of these fields, which is autonomous from the other instances of `RichIndustrialist`.

```
private String Name;
private double holdings;
private int Alive;
```

Here is a good description of static from the Java Tutorial

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Your properties/variables are static. and we know static variable are shared between all the objects.

That is the reason the last object will replace the existing value of your variables

Suggestion:

change your static modifier to instance modifier

From

```
private static String Name;
private static double holdings;
private static int Alive;
```

To

```
private String Name;
private double holdings;
private int Alive;
```

I am sure your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the `Name` member field in all of your classes, you should only declare it in the `super`-class and let the other `sub`-classes (re)use it.

Furthermore, you declared the field as `static`, all instances of your class will use the same field, which is probably not what you intended, so remove the `static` part.

Same goes for all of your other member fields.

*Note*: do not start the member fields with a capital: `Name` should be defined and used as `name`. Class names on the other hand should start with a capital! This is a generically accepted Java convention and keeps things more clear/separated.

Comment: Thank you all... I checked to non static and it fixed the problem :)